# Solution search solved using DFS or Greedy BFS?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I have a problem that sounds like this: A company has 4 taxis in 4 different (A B C D) locations. 4 people (W X Y Z) call the company that they need a taxi. I need to find the fastest way that the taxis can arrive at their people knowing that a taxi can only go for 1 person and each taxi has assigned a value between its destination and the people's destinations.

I was thinking of building a tree with all the possible combinations ex: AW-BX-CY-DZ or AX-BW-CY-DZ etc and find the minimum cost for each of them but I need to solve this using the DFS or greedy BFS approach. Any ideas how this would work? I can't imagine it.

I just want the idea on how to solve this using DFS/GBFS. I can't figure out how it would have to go or when the search would end since I'm looking for the minimum distance used

Comment: What is the objective function? That is, how do you compare two different matchings?

Answer (score 2):

This is an instance of an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which is finding maximum/minimum weight matching in a weighted bipartite graph. Most common algorithm used to solve this kind of problem is the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), solving it in O(n^3). There is a Python module implementing it - [munkres](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/).

However, If You really want to use DFS/BFS You can think of some naive algorithm creating every possible solution, and then searching through the solution space using DFS/BFS, but it will be highly nonoptimal.